# Disable webpage error messages vb app

Tags: vb.net, html

I´m developing a visual basic forms application, I call itself "Robot", and I have some problems with it.

The Robot has a Webrowser object that navigates to a website and searches for info. While navigating for that website sometimes a message box with title "Message from webpage" appears reporting that an exception has ocurred, It says something like "javax.NoRowAvailableException on row #XX from server...". This message box stops my Robot execution. When I press the OK button and the message box closes, the robot goes on.

The question is: ¿How can I disable or ignore that message box errors? I need my robot to work without stoping.

Thank you !!

Comment: The [`WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed(v=vs.110).aspx) might be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you but seems not to be working. I have been trying it but the messages still show up. I think they may be server log error messages, not script errors, so they appear even with The  WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed Property set to True.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some script of the Website is displaying errors using a javascript `Alert`. You can disable the messagebox shown for these errors in the `WebBrowser` control by setting its `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property to `true`.

See the following link on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you but seems not to be working. I have been trying it but the messages still show up. I think they may be server log error messages, not script errors, so they appear even with The WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed Property set to True.